# Django. How to display json file in html <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td><td>date</td></tr> tags?

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I suppose it,s silly question, but I'm new in json, so any anwser will help.

I  have json file:

```
`{"aaData": [
[1, "70.1700", "2008-12-29 11:23:00"],
[2, "70.2600", "2008-12-29 16:22:00"],
[3, "70.6500", "2008-12-30 11:30:00"],
[4, "70.8700", "2008-12-30 16:10:00"],
[5, "70.5500", "2009-01-02 11:09:00"],
[6, "70.6400", "2009-01-02 16:15:00"],
[7, "70.6500", "2009-01-05 11:17:00"]
]}`
```

my_app.html:

```
<li><a href="{%  url  'my_app.views.specific_document'  document.id  %}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
```

here is  my view function:

```
    def specific_document(request, document_id=1):
        json_file = Document.objects.get(id=document_id).docfile.url
        mydata = json.loads(json_file)
        return render(request, 'specific_document.html', {"mydata": mydata, "documents": documents}, content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

How the template 'specific_document.html' should look like to display data like I asked in the topic?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the table you should put something like this:

```
<table>
    {% for name, items in mydata.iteritems %}
        <!-- name = 'aaData' and items = [ list of entries ] -->
        {% for item in items %}
            <!-- item is ["number", "value", "date"] and you can access them by index -->
            <!-- Name -->
         <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <!-- Value -->
            <td>{{item.1}}</td>
            <!-- Date -->
            <td>{{item.2}}</td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here I'm going through the dictionary first (`for name, items in mydata.iteritems`) and then through each of the entries in the list of that dictionary entry.